# Map appropriate Resource (.resx) file in code - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, cultureinfo, resx

I have the following resource files in my ASP.NET MVC application to stored form validation error message for both English and Spanish

`ErrorMessages.resx` -- English Error Messages
`ErrorMessages.sp.resx` -- Spanish Error Messages

In my models that require the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` Required Attributes they are marked like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName)]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

In my controller, I am reading a JavaScript cookie that contains the user's selected language on the site and programmatically set the 'CultureInfo' of the current thread and the HTTP session:

```
public ActionResult MyController() 
{
    var language = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["language"].Value;

    if(language.Equals("english")) 
    {
        HttpContext.Session["culture"] = "en-US";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    }
    else 
    {
        HttpContext.Session["culture"] = "es-US";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-US");
    }
}
```

How do I set the appropriate resource file once the CultureInfo value has been modified?

Comment: spanish .resx file should *.es.resx, not *.sp.resx

Comment: I renamed my files to the appropriate `CultureInfo` value.  Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Spanish .resx file should be *.es.resx, not *.sp.resx.

In order to resolve translations from an appropriate **.resx** file you need to assign `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`, not `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`

Comment: When I switched to `CurrentUICulture` property, it is still using the english ErrorMessages.resx file.  I need my app to know when `CurrentUICulture = "es-US"` use the ErrorMessages.sp.resx

Comment: I did get it to work.  I modified my code to the following: `Thread.CurrrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-US");`

Comment: @MichaelKniskern why do not you post an answer, so others can benefit from it too ?

Comment: I just updated the question with what I did to get it to work.

Comment: @MichaelKniskern, you suppose to post it as an answer, not add an answer to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Koryakinp suggestion, I modified the controller code to the following:

```
var language = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["language"].Value;

if(language.Equals("english"))
{
    HttpContext.Session["culture"] = "en-US";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
}
```

Also, I had to restructure the .resx files. I created a .resx named "ErrorMessages" as the base .resx and renamed the existing .resx files:

`ErrorMessages.resx`
 
`ErrorMessages.en-US.resx`
 
`ErrorMessages.es-US.resx`